# Can't get SSH working anymore on Debian after upgrade

Tags: ssh

I have a vServer and can only login via SSH. After the latest `apt-get upgrade` command, I can't login anymore and get the following error message:

```
"Network error: Connection refused".
```

It seems that port 22 is not open anymore?

Fortunately, I'm able to use Virtuozzo offered by my provider that creates a repair container. From that I'm able to login in a special container (seems to be a new environment where all my files are mapped to a `/repair` folder).

I checked the `auth.log` file already:

```
Jul  7 22:29:13 v34913 saslauthd[1675]: detach_tty      : master pid is: 1675
Jul  7 22:29:13 v34913 saslauthd[1675]: ipc_init        : listening on socket: /var/run/saslauthd/mux
```

- Does that help?
- What else can I check why the ssh server is not running anymore?

Comment: Is `sshd` running? If not, that's your problem, and you can first try with `service ssh start`.

Comment: It says "[ ok ] Starting OpenBSD Secure Shell server: sshd.", but I think that doesn't help much, because this command is running in my virtual container and my original system is only mounted in "/repair".

Comment: Instead of this repair container, couldn't you log via a virtual console? This is just similar to physical logging, so that there is no need for a `sshd` on your VPS. This is usually done by doing a ssh to a special address. Ask your provider if you don't know.

Comment: I'll hazard a guess and say the machine isn't booting at all.  Does it require any special file-system or device drivers, given the environment, that may not have been built for the kernel you may or may not have upgraded to?

Comment: Yes, it's possible that the machine cannot boot. I had such problems in the past with my VPS, each time because the disk couldn't be mounted (once because fsck errors, and another time because of unknown-block(0,0) followed by a kernel panic). All these errors could be seen on the virtual console, which is just like physical keyboard and screen (mainly a screen when there are such failures). That's the best thing to know what's going on.

Comment: Are you able to `ping` the host? That should tell us if the system has booted to a state where networking is active, assuming that there is no firewall blocking ping requests.